# Forgot Yahoo password, but auto-signed in

Tags: account-recovery, yahoo-account

I've forgotten my Yahoo password. I can already see from the similar questions box that this is a common question on this site. But fortunately, my situation is better than most: I'm already signed in, and in fact I'm signed in everytime I go to a Yahoo website on Microsoft Edge.

I've tried just going to change the password. Unfortunately, when I do so, Yahoo first prompts me for my current password. I've also tried Yahoo's usual password recovery process; it doesn't work because the only recovery option I set up is a phone number which has since expired.

My worry is that eventually I'll get signed out of Yahoo and never be able to get in again. That would be very sad; I've had this account for over a decade and a half. Every once in a long while, I get prompted to change the password; and I just don't remember the latest one.

There are two ways I think I could resolve this:

- Password guessing. There are only so many passwords I use, and I'm pretty sure I could guess right within maybe 5-10 tries. My worry here is this may cause me to get kicked out of my account 'for security reasons'. So my first question is: Will this in fact happen, and if so how many tries do I get before I am kicked out?
- The fact that I auto sign in whenever I go to Yahoo indicates the password must be stored somewhere on my computer. I tried opening Settings -> Passwords on Microsoft Edge; but it isn't there. This probably means the password is instead stored in a cookie. My second question is then: Would it be possible to extract the password from a cookie?

Thanks

Comment: How do you access Yahoo mail? in a browser (such as Firefox) or some other email client. Please [edit] your question to advise.

Comment: @User24601 As stated in the first paragraph, and again in the second bullet point, I use Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @J.D. have you tried contacting Yahoo's customer service?